# Event that listens for ANY dropdown select?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have MULTIPLE divs, where each div consists of text followed by a dropdown followed by a textfield, like so:

```
<div>
Punch <select>
         <option>Hawaiin Punch</option>
         <option>Vodka</option>
     <select/>
     <input type="text" id="textfield_2"></input>
</div>
```

My complete example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/HsF2Y/3/

Do the following:

1. Type "lemons, " into the textfield.
2. Select "Vodka" from the dropdown; it gets appended to "lemons".  Type ", " after it.
3. Select
   "Vodka" again; the text remains the same.

I want to listen for an event other than "change" so that step 3 causes "Vodka" to be appended again.  So after all 3 steps, my textfield should show the text: "lemons, Vodka, Vodka".  Can somebody correct the code in the fiddle please?  Thanks.

Comment: You can't, the change event only fires when the select actually changes, selecting the same value again does not trigger the event, and there are no other events that would work like that either. Closest you'll get is "click", but that would fire everytime you click the select, and options don't fire events, so that's out.

Comment: How do i get my desired behavior then?

Comment: You don't! You have to use something other than a select to do that.

Comment: well, you could reset your dropdown to say "please select", after someone types ",", so you'd be able to catch the change event again and append the text in step3. Alternative you could add a button instead of the  user typing "," to trigger this behavior

Comment: As stated above because there is no change, it will not add a second 'string' of the same value. You could fairly easily add a quantity value, which depending on its value would just add the string n amounts of times.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a blank option to each select can do something like this:

```
$("select.choices").change(function () {
    if (this.value) {
        $(this).next().trigger('doUpdate', [this.value]);
        /* reset after selections updated*/
        this.value = "";
    }
});

$('.selections').each(function () { /* loop each so data array unique*/
    $(this).data('selections', []).on('doUpdate', function (evt, newVal) {
        var data = $(this).data('selections')
        data.push(newVal)
        this.value= data.join();
    }).change(function(){
         /* for manually added store new array*/
        var arr= $.trim(this.value).split(',');
         $(this).data('selections',arr)
    });
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HsF2Y/7/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `click` instead of `change`?